# How to list all shared library from a core file in AIX

Tags: aix, core-file

In AIX, how to list all shared library from a core file, including explicitly attached using dlopen()? Command ldd only lists statically loaded shared library. Command procldd can list the explicitly attached library using dlopen(), but the input parameter is a running process ID instead of core file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with dbx there is the "map" command that will list the shared libraries.  I do not know about ones loaded with dlopen but I would think those would be included.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the command check_core can show all libraries. /usr/lib/ras/check_core core